# Elliptic Curve NAF scalar method

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation

I am new in Elliptic curve and I got a lot of knowledge through reading :) but I reached to NAF method as a scalar multiplication method, but don't understand how in this example get it:

```
Let k = 1234567 and its binary representation contains 21- bits:
100101101011010000111. In this 
11 1′s and 10 0′s can be found resulting in 20 doubling operations (D) and 10 point addition operations (A). The width-4 NAF
representation of 1234567 is
9 0 0 0 0 13 0 0 0 0 13 0 0 0 0 0 0 7. In this, an increased number of 0′
s can be
seen. The computational cost = 18D + 4A, assuming that the values 9P, 13P
and 7P are computed before hand and stored.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the double-and-add method of curve multiplication, we set single bits in the exponent.  For example, if we're at `1101000G`, we can double (to get `11010000G`) and then conditionally add $G$ (to set the lsbit, getting `11010001G`).

NAF extends this by noting that, with a bit of precomputation, we can insert several bits at once.  For example, if we're at `11010000G`, and we have `1101G` precomputed, we can add those together, getting `11011101G`.  In this example, we set 3 bits in the exponent with a single add - doing the same with double-and-add with require 3 point additions.

So, with 4-bit NAT, we start with the values $0G, 1G, 2G, ..., 15G$ precomputed.  If we are using the same $G$ repeatedly (e.g. $G$ is the curve 'generator point'), we can do those once and put them in a table.  Alternatively, we can compute those with 7 additions and 7 doublings.

Then, to compute `100101101011010000111G`, we start with the top 4 bits `1001`.  We have `1001G` in our precomputed table, so we start there.  Then, we keep on doubling until we reach `100100000G`; at this point, we have 4 bits (the `1101` pattern) in the target that is not expressed in our current value - we get the `1101G` value in our precomputed table and add it in, given `100101101G`.  We keep on going (adding in values from our precomputed table when we get 4 bits in the target that is not expressed in our current value) until we hit the end - in that case, there's a remaining `111G`, so we add that in, and we're done.

If you note the patterns of doublings and additions (with a doubling without an addition being signified by a 0), that pattern is the `9 0 0 0 0 13 0 0 0 0 13 0 0 0 0 0 0 7` that's found in quote.

With double-and-add, we end up using an expected $n/2$ additions to multiply by an $n$-bit scalar; with 4-bit NAF, we use an expected $n/5$ additions (and the number of doublings are about the same - 4 bit NAT uses 3 fewer) - that is not that bad of a savings.

On the other hand, if the attacker is able to listen into when we are performing the doublings versus the additions, he can gain some information on the scalar we're multiplying by - that can be bad (hence this algorithm may not be appropriate without additional masking in some circumstances).

There are even more aggressive ways of implementing point multiplications with elliptic curves; however that should help with understanding this one.

Comment: thanks a lot for nice explination, and sure this will added value to my knowledge about EC, but I have question, do you have the function of doubling and adding for this NAF 4bits method, because I want to know why we doubled 5 times after `1001`

Comment: @CiscoSaeed: we doubled 5 times after `1001` to get to `100100000`, so that we can add `1101` to get `100101101`

Comment: OK so first I took the 1st 4 bits `1001` then I faced `0` after and to pass it then need to double 5 times to reach the next 4 bits then I reached `1101` then I faced `0` then I doubled five to reach `1101` then I faced 4 Zeros how I get 6 doubles here? :-) onc more thing could you refer to me any example about adding additional masking because of security reason?

Comment: You do 7 (not 6) doubles to move from `10010110101101` to `100101101011010000000`, so that a single addition of `111` gets you to `100101101011010000111`, the target value

Comment: As for masking, well, there are a number of alternatives - the most common is "Coron Blinding", which is "to compute $xG$, you pick a random $r$ and compute $(x+rq)G$ (where $q$ is the order of the point).  Now, straight-forward Coron blinding doesn't work that well with curves such as P256 (which has a $q$ very close to a power of 2; that means that you need a large $r$ to disguise all the bits) - one way around it is to use a point multiply routine that's based on a radix which is not a power of 2 (e.g. 48); that implies a base conversion routine to base 48; however it can work...

Comment: Many thanks to you, you earned me a lot of valuable information :)